# I'm having trouble trying to get the character at an index

Tags: java, indexing, caesar-cipher

This is my code:

```
package ch3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class caesarCypher {

    static String inp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input;
        int x = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        inp = scan.nextLine();

        input = inp.length();
        System.out.println(input + inp);
        while (x < input) {
            x += 1;
            inp =  ((inp.charAt(x)) - 12);
        }   
    }
}
```

how would I go about setting the index of `inp` to x? So to rephrase, I'm trying to subtract the character, for example, a - 12 on the ASCII table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java caesar cipher code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242376/java-caesar-cipher-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a char array:

```
public class caesarCypher {

    static String inp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        inp = scan.nextLine();
        char[] inpArr = inp.toCharArray();

        input = inp.length();
        System.out.println(input + inp);
        for( int i = 0; i < input; i++)
        {
            inpArr[i] -= 12;
        }

        inp = new String( inpArr);
    }
}
```

As a side note, you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsExceptio`n from the below code. Use x, then increment it.

```
while (x < input) {
    x += 1;
    inp =  ((inp.charAt(x)) - 12);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your goal, you want to read in a String and then shift it's chars in the ascii table?

A char is a 16 bit unsigned number, a kinda int derivate, that's why it is interpreted as an int.

but you're trying to assign an int back to your `inp` String:

> inp =  ((inp.charAt(x)) - 12);

This fails of course.

Because Strings are immutable in java you have to create a new String every time.

You can use `Character.toString(char c)` to get the actual char from an int value in the ascii table. This will set an offset of 12 to your input string

```
   int offset = 12;
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   inp = scan.nextLine(); 
   String shifted ="";
   for (int i = 0; i < inp.length(); i++) {
        char c = (char)((inp.charAt(i)) - offset);
        shifted+= Character.toString(c);
    }  
    System.out.println(shifted);
    scan.close();
```